# Ellipse fit tangentally to a line modifying one axis

Tags: c++, c, graphics, 2d

A graphic of this problem is here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13390614/Question.jpg

Take an axis aligned ellipse with a fixed
minor axis, and stretch the ellipse along 
its major axis till it becomes tangental 
to some line segment (A in the graphic).

What are the coordinates of the tangental 
point (P), or, what would the major axis 
length be?

I know how to calc the major axis if I have 
the tangental point, and can calc the point 
if I have the major axis, but with neither,
I'm stumped

I have also solved this when the minor axis is
stretched along with the major, maintaining
the ratio. The problem is when one axis is 
fixed.

Any insights would be appreciated, especially
via trig.

Gary

Comment: how is this question c++ related? i'd say its just maths..

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
x^2/max^2 + y^2/fix^2 = 1; % ellipse
Ax + By + C = 0;            % segment line
```

Then

```
x^2/max^2 + (Ax + C)^2/(B*fix)^2 = 1; // Quadratic equation
```

Your solution is when discriminant is equal to 0.

```
   x^2   (1/max^2 + A^2/(B*fix)^2)   
+  x      2 AC/(B*fix)^2
+        C^2/(B*fix)^2 - 1  
= 0

a = (1/max^2 + A^2/(B*fix)^2);
b = 2 AC/(B*fix)^2;
c = C^2/(B*fix)^2 - 1.

b^2 = 4ac   ==>   a = b^2/c    ==>
a = 4(AC)^2/(B*fix)^4 / ( C^2/(B*fix)^2 - 1 )
1/max^2 = 4(AC)^2/(B*fix)^4 / ( C^2/(B*fix)^2 - 1 ) - A^2/(B*fix)^2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The point P has y-coordinate r^2/h, where r is the semi-minor axis of the ellipse (so here r=0.75) and h is the y-coordinate of the point where the extension of your segment meets the y-axis (call this point H).

Why is this?  Well, imagine that we know what the correct ellipse and point P are, and now perform the affine transformation (x, y) -> (kx, y) where k is chosen so that the ellipse turns into a circle.  This doesn't move H, since H is on the y axis, and it moves P to a point P' with the same y-coordinate so that HP' is the tangent segment from H to the circle of radius r.  By similar right triangles, P' (and thus P) has y-coordinate r^2/h.

Of course it might happen that P doesn't lie on the original segment but only its extension to a line, or that the vertical axis is actually the major axis of the resulting ellipse; you might need to check these depending on your application.